# Model Validation in laravel 5.1 not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am writing a rule in Model for mobile number validation this should be required, 10 digit , and must numeric. 
My rule is

```
'phone'=>'required|numeric|min:10'
```

It check up to 2nd level mean **required and numeric** validation but not **min** validation 
please help me to fix this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When validation like **min/max/size** are applied to numeric values, they're applied to the value, not the length. So in your case your validation makes sure that given **number is larger or equal to 10**.

Have a look at **digits** validation, it lets you define the exact number of digits a number should have: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-digits

```
'phone' => 'required|numeric|digits:10'
```